# Redirection operator, standard input and command parameters

Tags: io-redirection

I'm following "The Linux Command Line" by William Shotts.  From what I understood, the `>` operator saves standard output to file, and `<` take standard input from file.

If the keyboard is the default standard input and `<` only takes that input from some file, why is `ls -l` not equivalent to `ls < some_params.txt` where `some_params.txt` would contain `-l`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/883786/how-does-input-redirection-work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> why is `ls -l` not equivalent to `ls < some_params.txt` where `some_params.txt` would contain `-l`?

Because the command line isn't the standard input!

`ls` is not a very good example here, since it doesn't use standard input. It just processes the command line options it gets, looks through some directories, and prints a listing to standard output.

But consider something like `cat -n`. It takes the `-n` flag from the command line, then reads from its standard input, adds line numbers and prints to standard output. Without `< filename`, the input comes from the terminal (i.e. your keyboard). With it, it comes from a file.

What you could do is use command substitution to insert the contents of a file to the command line. `ls $(cat some_params.txt)` (or `ls $(< some_params.txt)` in shells that support it) would do what you propose.