# Quickest way to move a line in a text file before another line in a text file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, command-line, vim, text-formatting

I have the line number 55 in a text file which I want to move just before line number 23 in the same text file. I know that you can move lines up by a certain number of lines [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44920864/sed-move-a-line), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188078/how-do-i-move-a-line-in-a-text-file-up-or-down-by-one-line) but is it possible to append or prepend a line to another line instead of the verbose way of moving lines up or down a textfile?

I am open to answers using vim, sed or any other command line tool but the more concise the better

#### update:

The `sed` command `i` inserts text before a line which is similar to what I am looking for except that I want to insert a line before a line

Comment: both mentioned links have solutions done by `ed`, have you tried them?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest , I'm not familiar with `ed` but I also missed those solutions because I didn't scroll down far enough

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A scriptable editor makes this pretty straight-forward!

```
printf '%s\n' '55m22' 'wq' | ed -s input
```

This sends two commands to `ed` (editing the file named `input`):

1. `55m22` -- move line 55 after line 22
2. `wq` -- save the file back to disk and quit.

Comment: It worked almost perfectly but I didn't read your answer fully so it moved line 55 after line 22, which is not a big deal just something to keep in mind. As for the command you posted: Why did you separate the two commands with a line break, usually when piping from one command to another the second command connected to the end of the pipe receives the output from the pipe as a series of arguments e.g. in a directory that contains directory1 and directory2 `echo * | ls -l` is equivalent to`ls -l directory1 directory2`. Why not `printf '%s ' '55m22' 'wq' | ed -s input'`?

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia that's not how pipes work and also not how `ls` works. The word splitting is usually done by the shell alone, but the shell does not modify what goes into the pipe. Pipes transfer raw data, it's up to the target program what to do with it. If `ed` expects one command per line, that is what you have to provide.

Comment: I used `22` because the `m`ove command moves the addressed line *after* the target line and you wanted it to land before line `23`.

Comment: @frostschutz , thanks for the correction, can you specify which part of my description of a pipe was misinformed? Is it the bit about a series of arguments or the command after the pipe being connected to the end of the pipe? As for the "word splitting being done by the shell alone", isn't the command line user the one that specifies the word splitting to the shell in the form of `\n` (line feed), ` ` (white space), `\r` (carriage return) etc.?

Comment: The line break you see in the `printf` format sends the commands with a newline so that `ed` sees them as two separate commands, just as if you had run `ed` interactively.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia, `echo * | ls` doesn't make sense because `ls` doesn't read stdin, [it's not equivalent to `ls -l *`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/531285/redirection-operator-standard-input-and-command-parameters). Word splitting means the [splitting that happens to unquoted expansions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary), it doesn't seem to apply here.

Comment: I like to see good old ed still used (it is very usefull on large files, for exemple). good answer.

Comment: Obligatory [ed, man! !man ed](https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html)

Answer (score 4):

A little shorter:

```
ex input <<<"55m22|wq"
```

Comment: If you are assuming this level of shell support, one could also write `ed -s input <<< $'55m22\nwq'`. The main benefit to using `ex` would be the ability to use a single pipe-delimited command rather than a series of newline-terminated commands. Otherwise, you would write `printf '55m22|wq\n' | ex input`, which saves three characters over `printf '55m22\nwq\n' | ed -s input`.

Answer (score 3):

It's somewhat longer in `vi` than in `ed`:

```
vi input
55Gdd23GPZZ
```

`55G` ... go to line 55
`dd` ... delete one line
`23G` ... go to line 23
`P` ... paste the deleted line before line 23
`ZZ` ... write file and exit

Comment: `vi` also has the [`:m`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Am) command, same as `ed`, so `:55m22` is also possible in `vi`.

Comment: Thank you, @filbranden!

Comment: Historically, `vi` was a refinement of `ex`, which itself was a refinement of `ed`.